# Inverse and block multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm not even sure where to begin here. I don't get any information on these 'blocks' of matrices...Can someone tell me how I'd go about solving problems such as this one?

Comment: *Finding* an inverse is not always easy, but *verifying* an inverse is. Have you thought about how to multiply block matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that you can multiply block matrices in the "usual" way. So note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
O & D 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1} & -A^{-1}BD^{-1} \\ 
O & D^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
AA^{-1}+BO & -AA^{-1}BD^{-1}+BD^{-1} \\
OA^{-1}+DO& -OA^{-1}BD^{-1}+DD^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} 
=?
$$
Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Ah, it gives me the identity! I See! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I don't really understand how you are multiplying these? Seems you only multiply the A first and then randomly multiply things...Doesn't look like normal matrix multiplication at all!

Comment: @user3200098 edited it to make even more clear

Comment: Yeah I was starting to see it. So $O$ is a null matrix?

Comment: @user3200098 That's what I'm assuming from the context of the problem.

Comment: I notice that when you multiply $A \cdot -A^{-1}$ you simply write $-AA^{-1}$. I am multiplying (in another problem) $B \cdot -C(I-BC)^{-1}$. Would I write this as $-CB(I-BC)^{-1}$ or $B(-C(I-BC)^{-1}$? Thanks

Comment: @user3200098 Scalars always factor out of matrix multiplication: $A\cdot(\lambda B)=\lambda\cdot(AB)$. In this instance we are dealing with the scalar $\lambda=-1$.

Comment: Ah cool. Gonna scratch myself through this problem (It's the same type, just uglier). I may throw a question here if I get stuck, if you don't mind.

Comment: Does $(I-BC)^{-1} = I^{-1}-BC^{-1}$? Does $I(I-BC)^{-1} = (I^2-IBC)^{-1}$? Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3200098 The answer to that question is no, but I think it's best if you post further inquiries as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference on block multiplication:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockMatrix.html

Now you just need to show that $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} A&B\\0&D \end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} A^{-1}&-A^{-1}BD^{-1}\\0&D^{-1} \end{array}\right]
=
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} I&0\\0&I \end{array}\right]$$